# Does the distributional antiderivative of a $L^p$ function always exist?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

So say I have $f\in L^p$. Is there always a function $g\in L^p$ such that
$$
\langle f,-\phi_x\rangle = \langle g,\phi\rangle
$$
for all $\phi\in C^\infty_c$. Or phrased differently if $f\in L^p$ does $g\in W^{1,p}$ with $g_x=f$ exist?

(at least on bounded domains)

I think so but I'm not sure. My proof would be:

Define the distribution $T_{g(f)}(\phi) = \langle f,-\phi_x\rangle$. Then in a lecture I was told that if $T$ is a distribution and $\partial_1 T,\dots,\partial_n T\in \text{RM}_{\text{loc}}$ then $T\in L^1_\text{loc}$. So by Hölder's inequality $\partial_x T_g\in L^1_{\text{loc}}$ such that $T_g\in L^1_\text{loc}$. Using the same technique again I get that the second antiderivative is $L^1_{\text{loc}}$ and therefore in $W^{1,1}_{\text{loc}}$ which in turn by Sobolev embedding implies that $T_g$ is continuous and therefore $L^p_{\text{loc}}$

Is this true?

Comment: You got a typo in the first align I assume? Else $g = -f$ would do the job.

Comment: Yes of course. Thanks!

Comment: Since I believe you are looking for an answer where $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ for $n \geq 2$ as a domain is allowed I am a little confused by the notation. What does $\phi_x$ mean? Do you mean to denote a partial derivative?

Comment: Is it in $1$ dimension or in higher dimension? In higher dimensions you have problems defining an antiderivative ...
In dimension $1$, this is the usual antiderivative $g = ∫ f$. Of course, it verifies what you are writing.

Comment: The underlying problem is in $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$, but in the particular question I'm interested if this works for 1 dimension. Yes $\phi_x$ is the partial derivative of $\phi$ with respect to $x$.

Comment: In dimension 1 and bounded domains $\Omega=(a,b)$ the answer is or course yes, just set $g(x):=\int_a^x f(y) dy$. (It is easy to check by hand that indeed $g\in W^{1,p}$, and of course $g'=f$)